# Material not copying to other objects in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a material for hair that works great when using Eevee, but once I switch to cycles, it only appears to work on one object.  The rest of the objects don't appear to receive anything past the Principled BSDF shader despite sharing the same material.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason *Use UV for Mapping* is disabled in the *Properties > Curve Data > Texture Space* settings on all the objects except one.
To enable it for everything, select them all (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> might be useful), then right click on the *Use UV for Mapping* setting and click *Copy to selected*.

Comment: Bingo!  Not sure why it didn't duplicate with the rest, but it appears to have solved the problem.  Thank you so much!